# .NET Authentication and AJAX

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, authentication, .net-3.5

Is there anyway to stop a page from refreshing after a successful login?  I have a scriptmanager and updatepanel around a login control which works and there is no refresh on an error, but it ALWAYS refreshes on login.  How do I stop that?

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if your code for the login's success action contains a redirect statement to the same page. If it does remove it.

Comment: I have no code that redirects. I have an OnClick that is run and I want to inject JS that pops up the change password box, but apparently the page just refreshes on login